# Using inheritance of builders in GO

Tags: go

I need to create builder (base) and specific builders for each build type.

```
e.g.

builder for html project
builder for node.js project
builder for python project
builder for java project
```

….

The main functionality will be like following:

**File:Builder.go**

interface

```
type Builder interface {
    Build(string) error
}
```

**File: nodebuilder.go**

```
//This is the struct ???? not sure what to put here...
type Node struct {


}


func (n Node) Build(path string) error {

//e.g. Run npm install which build's nodejs projects

        command := exec.Command("npm", "install")
        command.Dir = “../path2dir/“

        Combined, err := command.CombinedOutput()

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        log.Printf("%s", Combined)
    }

    ...
    //return new(error)
}
```

**Main assumptions/process:**

1. To start build on each module I need to get the path to it
2. I need to copy the module to a temp folder
3. I need to run the build on it (implement the build interface like `mvn build` `npm install` etc)
4. After build was finished zip the module with dep
5. Copy it to new target folder

Note: beside from the `build` and the `path` (that should be handled specifically ) all other functionality are identical
**like** `zip` `copy`

> 1. Where should I put the the `zip and copy` (in the structure) and for example how should I implement them and path them to the builder ?
> 2. Should I structure the project differently according the assumptions?

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Can you give a concrete example of how your builders are supposed to be called? If you want common code to invoke them, just make a `Builder` interface with a `Build()` method. If you want to use a `BaseBuilder`, have each other builder embed that struct. Again, some clarification and use example would help.

Comment: @Marc - This is not implemented yet and I want to make the design before written the code and before doing mistakes since im new to golang...any direction will be helpful since all the examples that I find in golang are too basic

Comment: Except this isn't how SO works, especially not with such a vague description. We really need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest trying some solutions out yourself based on your requirements and seeing what works. Then ask here if you run into specific issues.

Comment: There is no inheritance in Go and thus no real "base" types. I would recommend reassessing your design based on the language in which it is being implemented.

Comment: @Adrian - Ok thanks, can you give a direction some reference for this such problem ?  how it good to implement ?

Comment: @Adrian - also git reference for project that are using the same logic will be great...

Comment: That's much too broad and opinionated a question for SO.  Try Reddit, or maybe reading some of the bountiful Go source that's already available publicly, including the standard library and 3rd-party libraries on GitHub.

Comment: Throughout, you're talking about _"inheritance"_. Whilst understandable, you need to come to terms with the simple fact of the matter that golang has no classical inheritance. You can embed types (ie composition), but you cannot inherit. FWIW, I'd look at implementing a generic `Builder` interface, and just load the builders you need

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - Thanks a lot for the  direction, it will be great if you can provide some simple example how to do it ...im coming from javasc and it a bit confusing... thanks!!!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - I've update the question with bounty, it will be great if you can have a look and provide example how to do it...thanks

Comment: @Marc -I've update the question with bounty, it will be great if you can have a look and provide example how to do it...thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first principle of **SOLID** says that a piece of code should have only one responsibility.

Takes the context in, it really makes no sense that any `builder` to care about the `copy` and `zip` part of the build process. It's beyond `builder`'s responsibility. Even using composition (embedding) is not neat enough.

Narrow it down, the `Builder`'s core responsibility is to build the code, as the name suggests. But more specifically, the `Builder`'s responsibility is to build the code at a path. What path? The most idomatic way is the **current path**, the **working dir**. This adds two side methods to the interface: `Path() string` which returns the **current path** and `ChangePath(newPath string) error` to change the **current path**. The implentation would be simple, preserve a single string field as the current path would mostly do the job. And it can easily be extended to some remote process.

If we looks it carefully, there auctually is two *build* concepts. One is the whole building **process**, from making temp dir to copy it back, all five steps; the other is the build **command**, which is the third step of the process.

That is very inspiring. A process is idomatic to be presented as a function, as classic procedural programing would do. So we write a `Build` function. It serialize all the 5 steps, plain and simple.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
)

//A builder is what used to build the language. It should be able to change working dir.
type Builder interface {
    Build() error //Build builds the code at current dir. It returns an error if failed.
    Path() string //Path returns the current working dir.
    ChangePath(newPath string) error //ChangePath changes the working dir to newPath.
}

//TempDirFunc is what generates a new temp dir. Golang woould requires it in GOPATH, so make it changable.
type TempDirFunc func() string

var DefualtTempDirFunc = func() string {
    name,_ := ioutil.TempDir("","BUILD")
    return name
}

//Build builds a language. It copies the code to a temp dir generated by mkTempdir
//and call the Builder.ChangePath to change the working dir to the temp dir. After
//the copy, it use the Builder to build the code, and then zip it in the tempfile,
//copying the zip file to `toPath`.
func Build(b Builder, toPath string, mkTempDir TempDirFunc) error {

    if mkTempDir == nil {
        mkTempDir = DefaultTempDirFunc
    }

    path,newPath:=b.Path(),mkTempDir()
    defer removeDir(newPath) //clean-up

    if err:=copyDir(path,newPath); err!=nil {
        return err
    }
    if err:=b.ChangePath(newPath) !=nil {
        return err
    }

    if err:=b.Build(); err!=nil {
        return err
    }

    zipName,err:=zipDir(newPath) // I don't understand what is `dep`.
    if err!=nil { 
        return err
    }

    zipPath:=filepath.Join(newPath,zipName)
    if err:=copyFile(zipPath,toPath); err!=nil {
        return err
    }


    return nil
}

//zipDir zips the `path` dir and returns the name of zip. If an error occured, it returns an empty string and an error.
func zipDir(path string) (string,error) {}

//All other funcs is very trivial.
```

Most of things are covered in the comments and I am really felling lazy to write all those `copyDir`/`removeDir` things. One thing that is not mentioned in the design part is the `mkTempDir` func. Golang would be unhappy if the code is in `/tmp/xxx/` as it is outside the `GOPATH`, and it would make more trouble to change `GOPATH` as it will break import path serching, so golang would require a unique function to generate a tempdir inside the `GOPATH`.

Edit:

Oh, one more thing I forgot to say. It is terribly ugly and irresponsible to handle errors like this. But the idea is there, and more decent error handling mostly requires the usage contents. So do change it yourself, log it, panic or whatever you want.

Edit 2:

You can re-use your npm example as following.

```
type Node struct {
    path string
}

func (n Node) Build(path string) error {
    //e.g. Run npm install which build's nodejs project
    command := exec.Command("npm", "install")
    command.Dir = n.path
    Combined, err := command.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%s", Combined)
    return nil
}

func (n *Node) ChangePath(newPath string) error {
    n.path = newPath
}

func (n Node) Path() string {
    return n.path
}
```

And to combine it with other language all together:

```
func main() {
    path := GetPathFromInput()
    switch GetLanguageName(path) {
    case "Java":
        Build(&Java{path},targetDirForJava(),nil)
    case "Go":
        Build(&Golang{path,cgoOptions},targetDirForGo(),GoPathTempDir()) //You can disable cgo compile or something like that.
    case "Node":
        Build(&Node{path},targetDirForNode(),nil)
    }
}
```

One trick is get language name. `GetLanguageName` should return the name of the language the code in `path` is using. This can be done by using `ioutil.ReadDir` to detect filenames.

Also note that although I made the `Node` struct very simple and only stores a `path` field, you can extend it easily. Like in `Golang` part, you might add build options there.

Edit 3:

About package structure:

First of all, I think literally everything: the `Build` function, language builders and other util/helpers should be put into a single package. They all work for a single task: build a language. There is no need and hardly any expectation to isolate any piece of code as another (sub)package.

So that means one dir. The remaining is really some very personal style but I will share mine:

I would put the function `Build` and interface `Builder` into a file called `main.go`. If the front-end code is minimal and very readable, I would put them into `main.go` as well, but if it is long and have some ui-logic, I would put it into a `front-end.go` or `cli.go` or `ui.go`, depending on the auctual code.

Next, for each language, I would create a `.go` file with the language code. It makes clear where I can check them. Alternatively, if the code is really tiny, it is not a bad idea to put them all together into a `builders.go`. After all, mordern editors can be more than capable to get definitaion of structs and types.

Finally, all the `copyDir`, `zipDir` functions goes to a `util.go`. That is simple - they are utilities, most time we just don't want to bother them.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating 1+  i'll test this and let you know

Comment: Thanks I'll like your idea, something that I missing here is how I combine the all process with the specific java / node builds , lets say i've two builds language how the flow will be, code example will be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @RaynD I have added what I think you are looking for. If it is not, please explain a bit more.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to play with the code and there is some issue's , is there a way to make it work simple (with some mocks) that I will be able to debug and understand it better , I've tried with https://play.golang.org/p/dAfOTQFRjTG and there is some error.last thing , if you need to create the project on GitHUB how would you structure it ? which package you put each file ? (drawing the structure is sufficient  ) . many thanks!

Comment: @RaynD Sure there is error, as the code is not fully implented. `copyDir` is missing and so on. And I have edited the sturcture into the answer. Please note that much is much more causal.

Comment: Can you please provide some working version , I mean with some mock to all the logic (return true / nil etc) , when I try to run it I got lot of errors which I cannot test the flow with. I just want to test the flow to see how it works e.g. the main just with one  option remove others , just some boilerplate that I can test ...Thank you!

Comment: @RaynD I am being sick and busy and the moment, but I will try to write one when I feel less dizzy.

Comment: ohh, hopefully you feel good soon. have a nice day :). looking forward ....thanks a lot

Comment: @RaynD It turns out I am too dissy to decide design on the project I am working on so I write this: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/leafbebop/re7yy5

Comment: The func ` TargetDirForNodeBuilder` is not part of the interface , if I put all the builders in the same package this is problem, isnt it ? can you update the bit bucket how this function should implemented  with additional builder and how it should call from the main ? (just copy past the node with minor changes to if you can) thank you

Comment: @RaynD this function is just a mock or a placeholder.  This is some code I don't think I can write for you. It very much depends on how you are going to use the package, and what "target dir" means to the package. It might be something the user inputs, or maybe something in a config file, or maybe a hardcoded dir, for that I don't know.

Comment: @RaynD Indeed it is not part of the the interface. it is more of how you implent the ui logic. And I don't think put all the builders in a package would raise any problem. It is not that re-usable, after all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it will be great if you can add to your example another builder(mock) and lets say i've 10 builder how do you handle it on the main, I mean 5 builders of node (as you write ) and 5 builder of any other language you choose how do you handle it on the main ( im talking about the loop on list of builders etc) , it will be great if you can add it. thanks!

Comment: I've accepted your answer, it will be great if you can response to my previous question... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Go is not an object-oriented language. This means that by design, you don't necessarily have all the behaviour of a type encapsulated in the type itself. And this is handy when you think that we don't have inheritance.

When you want to build a type upon another type, you use composition instead: a `struct` can embed other types, and expose their methods.

Let's say that you have a `MyZipper` type that exposes a `Zip(string)` method, and a `MyCopier` that exposes a `Copy(string)` method:

```
type Builder struct {
    MyZipper
    MyCopier
}

func (b Builder) Build(path string) error {

    // some code

    err := b.Zip(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err := b.Copy(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

An this is composition in Go. Going further, you can even embed non-exposed types (e.g. `myZipper` and `myCopier`) if you only want them to be called from within the `builder` package. But then, why embedding them in the first place?

You can chose between several different valid designs for your Go project.

#### solution 1: Single package exposing multiple Builder types

In this case, you want a `builder` package, that will expose multiple builders.

`zip` and `copy` are two functions defined somewhere in the package, they don't need to be methods attached to a type.

```
package builder

func zip(zip, args string) error {
    // zip implementation
}

func cp(copy, arguments string) error {
    // copy implementation
}

type NodeBuilder struct{}

func (n NodeBuilder) Build(path string) error {
    // node-specific code here

    if err := zip(the, args); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := cp(the, args); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

type PythonBuilder struct{}

func (n PythonBuilder) Build(path string) error {
    // python-specific code here

    if err := zip(the, args); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := cp(the, args); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

#### solution 2: single package, single type embedding specific behaviour

Depending on the complexity of the specific behaviour, you may not want to change the whole behaviour of the Build function, but just to inject a specific behaviour:

```
package builder

import (
    "github.com/me/myproj/copier"
    "github.com/me/myproj/zipper"
)

type Builder struct {
    specificBehaviour func(string) error
}

func (b Builder) Build(path string) error {
    if err := specificBehaviour(path); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := zip(the, args); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := copy(the, args); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func nodeSpecificBehaviour(path string) error {
    // node-specific code here
}

func pythonSpecificBehaviour(path string) error {
    // python-specific code here
}

func NewNode() Builder {
    return Builder{nodeSpecificBehaviour}
}

func NewPython() Builder {
    return Builder{pythonSpecificBehaviour}
}
```

#### solution 3: one package per specificBuilder

On the other end of the scale, depending on the package granularity you want to use in your project, you may want to have a distinct package for every builder. With this premise, you want to generalise the shared functionality enough to give it a citizenship as package too. Example:

```
package node

import (
    "github.com/me/myproj/copier"
    "github.com/me/myproj/zipper"
)

type Builder struct {
}

func (b Builder) Build(path string) error {
    // node-specific code here

    if err := zipper.Zip(the, args); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := copier.Copy(the, args); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

#### solution 4: functions!

If you know your builders will be purely functional, meaning they don't need any internal state, then you may want your Builders to be function types intead of interfaces. You will still be able to manipulate them as a single type from the consumer side, if this is what you want:

```
package builder

type Builder func(string) error

func NewNode() Builder {
    return func(string) error {

        // node-specific behaviour

        if err := zip(the, args); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if err := copy(the, args); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return nil
    }
}

func NewPython() Builder {
    return func(string) error {

        // python-specific behaviour

        if err := zip(the, args); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if err := copy(the, args); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

I wouldn't go with functions for your particular case, because you will need to solve very different problems with every BUilder, and you will definitely need some state at some point.

... I'll leave you the pleasure to combine together some of these techniques, if you are having a boring afternoon.

#### Bonus!

- Don't be afraid of creating multiple packages, as this will help you design clear boundaries between the types, and take full advantage of encapsulation.
- The `error` keyword is an interface, not a type! You can `return nil` if you have no errors.
- Ideally, you don't define the `Builder` interface in the `builder` package: you don't need it. The `Builder` interface will sit in the consumer package.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating 1+ , I like the option 1 but what I missing is how to use for example 2-3 builders (im talking just about the structuring)  and if using an interface how it should be done ,example on extended option one will be they way I want to go so it will be very helpful, I mean how you handle the structures, packages copy zip etc, thanks a lot!

Comment: In solution1, you have all the builder types in the same package. Theoretically speaking, they could be in the same file, although I prefer to have 1 file per type. `copy` and `zip` can be in their own files, in the same package. And you just expose the types: you will define the interface on the consumer package: most probably, the `main` package.

Comment: Speaking of tiny packages, Edward Muller had a talk on dotgo against it: https://about.sourcegraph.com/go/idiomatic-go#tiny-package-syndrome

Answer (score 4):

Let's go through each question one by one:

**1. Where should I put the the zip and copy (in the structure) and for example how should I implement them and path them to the builder ?**

An interface does not carry any data (assuming you wanted to implement one from your code). It is just a blueprint an object can implements in order to pass as a more generic type. In this case, if you are not passing `Builder` type anywhere, the interface is redundant.

**2. Should I structure the project differently according the assumptions?**

This is my take on the project. I'll explain each part separately after the code:

```
package buildeasy

import (
        "os/exec"
)


// Builder represents an instance which carries information
// for building a project using command line interface.
type Builder struct {
        // Manager is a name of the package manager ("npm", "pip")
        Manager string
        Cmd     string
        Args    []string
        Prefn   func(string) error
        Postfn  func(string) error
}

func zipAndCopyTo(path string) error {
        // implement zipping and copy to the provided path
        return nil
}

var (
        // Each manager specific configurations
        // are stored as a Builder instance.
        // More fields and values can be added.
        // This technique goes hand-in-hand with
        // `wrapBuilder` function below, which is
        // a technique called "functional options"
        // which is considered a cleanest approach in
        // building API methods.
        // https://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/17/functional-options-for-friendly-apis
        NodeConfig = &Builder{
                Manager: "npm",
                Postfn:  zipAndCopyTo,
        }
        PythonConfig = &Builder{
                Manager: "pip",
                Postfn:  zipAndCopyTo,
        }
)

// This enum is used by factory function Create to select the
// right config Builder from the array below.
type Manager int

const (
    Npm Manager = iota
    Pip
    // Yarn
    // ...
)

var configs = [...]*Builder{
    NodeConfig,
    PythonConfig,
    // YarnConfig, 
}

// wrapBuilder accepts an original Builder and a function that can
// accept a Builder and then assign relevant value to the first.
func wrapBuilder(original *Builder, wrapperfn func(*Builder)) error {
    if original != nil {
        wrapperfn(original)
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("Original Builder is nil")
}

func New(manager Manager) *Builder {
    builder := new(Builder)
    // inject / modify properties of builder with relevant
    // value for the manager we want.
    wrapBuilder(builder, configs[int(manager)])
    })
    return builder
}

// Now you can have more specific methods like to install.
// notice that it doesn't matter what this Builder is for.
// All information is contained in it already.
func (b *Builder) Install(pkg string) ([]byte, error) {
    b.Cmd = "install"

    // if package is provided, push its name to the args list
    if pkg != "" {
        b.Args = append([]string{pkg}, b.Args...)
    }

    // This emits "npm install [pkg] [args...]"
    cmd := exec.Command(b.Manager, (append([]string{b.Cmd}, b.Args...))...)
    // default to executing in the current directory
    cmd.Dir = "./"

    combined, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return combined, nil
}



func (b *Builder) Build(path string) error {
    // so default the path to a temp folder
    if path == "" {
        path = "path/to/my/temp"
    }

    // maybe prep the source directory?
    if err := b.Prefn(path); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Now you can use Install here
    output, err := b.Install("")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("%s", output)

    // Now zip and copy to where you want
    if err := b.Postfn(path); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Now this `Builder` is generic enough to handle most build commands. Notice `Prefn` and `Postfn` fields. These are hook functions you can run before and after the command runs within `Build`. `Prefn` can check if, say, the package manager is installed and install it if it's not (or just return an error). `Postfn` can run your `zip` and `copy` operations, or any clean up routine. Here's a usecase, provided `superbuild` is our fictional package name and the user is using it from outside:

```
import "github.com/yourname/buildeasy"

func main() {

        myNodeBuilder := buildeasy.New(buildeasy.NPM)
        myPythonBuilder := buildeasy.New(buildeasy.PIP)

        // if you wanna install only
        myNodeBuilder.Install("gulp")

        // or build the whole thing including pre and post hooks
        myPythonBuilder.Build("my/temp/build")

        // or get creative with more convenient methods
        myNodeBuilder.GlobalInstall("gulp")
}
```

You can predefine a few `Prefn`s and `Postfn`s and make them available as option for the user of your program, assuming it's a command line program, or if it's a library, have the user write them herself.

**wrapBuilder function**

There are a few techniques used in constructing an instance in Go. First, parameters can be passed into a constructor function (this code is for explanation only and not to be used):

```
func TempNewBuilder(cmd string) *Builder {
        builder := new(Builder)
        builder.Cmd = cmd
        return builder
}
```

But this approach is very ad-hoc because it is impossible to pass arbitrary values to configure the returned `*Builder`. A more robust approach is to pass a `config` instance of `*Builder`:

```
func TempNewBuilder(configBuilder *Builder) *Builder {
     builder := new(Builder)
     builder.Manager = configBuilder.Manager
     builder.Cmd = configBuilder.Cmd
     // ...
     return builder    
}
```

By using `wrapBuilder` function, you can write a function to handle (re)assigning of values of an instance:

```
func TempNewBuilder(builder *Builder, configBuilderFn func(*Builder)) *Builder {
     configBuilderFn(builder)
}
```

Now you can pass in any function for `configBuilderFn` to configure your `*Builder` instance.

To read more, see https://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/17/functional-options-for-friendly-apis.

**configs array**

`configs` array goes hand-in-hand with the enum of `Manager` constants. Take a look at `New` factory function. the enum constant `manager` passed in pass the parameter is type `Manager` which is just an `int` underneath. This means all we had to do is access `configs` using the `manager` as the index in `wrapBuilder`:

```
wrapBuilder(builder, configs[int(manager)])
```

For instance, if `manager == Npm`,`configs[int(manager)]` will return `NodeConfig` from `configs` array.

**Structuring package(s)**

At this point, it is fine to have `zip` and `copy` functions to live in the same package as `Build` the way I did. There's little use in prematurely optimizing anything or worry about that until you have to. That will only introduce more complexity than you'd want. Optimization comes consistently as you develop the code.

If you feel like structuring the project early is important, you can do it based on the semantic of your API. For instance, to create a new `*Builder`, it is quite intuitive for the user to call a factory function `New` or `Create` from a subpackage `buildeasy/builder`:

```
// This is a user using your `buildeasy` package

import (
        "github.com/yourname/buildeasy"
        "github.com/yourname/buildeasy/node"
        "github.com/yourname/buildeasy/python"
)

var targetDir = "path/to/temp"

func main() {
        myNodeBuilder := node.New()   
        myNodeBuilder.Build(targetDir)
        myPythonBuilder := python.New()
        myPythonBuilder.Install("tensorflow")   
}
```

Another more verbose approach is to include the semantic as part of the function's name, which is also used in Go's standard packages:

```
myNodeBuilder := buildeasy.NewNodeBuilder()
myPythonBuilder := buildeasy.NewPipBuilder()

// or 
mySecondNodeBuilder := buildeasy.New(buildeasy.Yarn)
```

In Go's standard packages, verbose functions and methods are common. That's because it normally structure sub-packages (subdirectories) for more specific utilities such as [path/filepath](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#pkg-subdirectories), which contains utility functions related to file path manipulation while keeping `path`'s API basic and clean.

Coming back to your project, I would keep most common, more generic functions at the top level directory/package. This is how I would tackle the structure:

```
buildeasy
├── buildeasy.go
├── python
│   └── python.go
└── node/
    └── node.go
```

While package `buildeasy` contains functions like `NewNodeBuilder`, `NewPipBuilder`, or just `New` that accepts additional options (like the above code), in subpackage `buildeasy/node`, for instance, can look like this:

```
package node

import "github.com/yourname/buildeasy"

func New() *buildeasy.Builder {
        return buildeasy.New(buildeasy.Npm)
}

func NewWithYarn() *buildeasy.Builder {
        return buildeasy.New(buildeasy.Yarn)
}

// ...
```

or `buildeasy/python`:

```
package python

import "github.com/yourname/buildeasy"

func New() *buildeasy.Builder {
        return buildeasy.New(buildeasy.Pip)
}

func NewWithEasyInstall() *buildeasy.Builder {
        return buildeasy.New(buildeasy.EasyInstall)
}

// ...
```

Note that in the subpackages you never have to call `buildeasy.zipAndCopy` because it is a private function that is lower level than the `node` and `python` subpackages should care. these subpackages act like another layer of API calling `buildeasy`'s functions and passing in some specific values and configurations that make life easier for the user of its API.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, Assume that I've two builders one node and python , how would you write all the process (the main throw the builder and builders ) to handle the logic (just example not real implementations ) , I miss the whole flow ...Thanks a lot

Comment: @RaynD can you elaborate the question? I don't think I understand it.

Comment: Sure :) , Lets say you have `main` function and you should handle two type of different builders(node/java/any_other ) two is sufficient to get the point ...,  (you can put the method of `copy` and `zip` and `temp folder` as empty  implementation), I just want to get the point how  the `process` will be executed from `main` until `executing the builders`. if you need to write this new project in `GitHub` how would you `structure it` ?  where the `zip logic` will be (which package) same for `copy` and the `specific builders` and the builder process. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've added much more, and there might be typos and a farcry from optimized. The first step in creating a tool is to think hard about how natural it is to use from the user's POV, and that means the API or methods you expose. For example, you might add extra parameters to `Create` so the user can write their own `pre` and `post` hooks to override or compliment the default ones, but that is a design decision too.

Comment: Thank you! , I've try to play with your direction to understand the concept more and I got some error (some of then was fixed) , can you please have a look , https://play.golang.org/p/O60aSu4nJnO , in addition if you want to build this project on GITHUB (from scratch) , how would you structure it , where do you put each file , something like this https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1  will be very helpful   (like section 4 drawing the structure will be great ) many thanks!

Comment: @RaynD thanks for pointing out, the corrected version is here https://play.golang.org/p/xAcqvqNNfOo. Note that still you couldn't use `os/exec` on playground and previously there were "placeholders" in the code preventing it from being compiled.

Comment: 1. it will be great if you can add to the working version play.golang.org/p/O60aSu4nJnO some high-level content for the wrapper (since I dont understand what it the purpose of it in the flow, I guess i miss something very helpful ...) , inside the wrapper as I understand (not sure if true) you mean to provide the builder specific logic , but its not better to create specific file that will handle each builder logic ? can this adopt in your design ? (I believe in `SOC` )...  , in addition what is the `configs` object for ?

Comment: also if I put it like this NodeConfig = &Builder{ Manager: "npm", Cmd:"npm install", Postfn: zipAndCopyTo, } noting happen... , any idea? and also what is the need for the `npmWrapper` and how it should be used ? thanks a lot sir!

Comment: `Cmd` should only be the second argument of the command line input. In this case `"install"`. It should look like this `NodeConfig = &Builder{ Manager: "npm", Cmd: "install", ... }`. Ignore the `npmWrapper` in playground it was dead code.

Comment: Can you please explain about the `wrapBuilder`, why we need it ? which design benefit this give ?  (sorry but I miss the point...) in addition also why we need the `configs`  var ?  it will be great if you have a time to do last mile and make the example work just with node ...I mean how you see it should work...Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: I've added some more text to explain, if you like this is getting too long let's take it in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163406/go-language-learning.