# Execute command's and ZIP folder as async in Go

Tags: go

I’ve a program which executes some command via `cmd := exec.Command(name, args…)`
Now the program is doing this for 10(or more) different directories,
I mean I run `npm install` for 10 different directories for given path.
The idea is to `wait` that the execute process will **end** and than zip the entire folder (where the command npm install was run)
The Problem here is that that when the `wait` block is executing the program stops and wait (like it should do of course…) but I want in to **proceed to the next directory** and don't wait to the `wait` (of each directory execution ) to finish

How it’s suggested to handle it in sufficient way ? 
I mean to wait the minimum between executing the modules and
in addition when specific  command is finished to run on specified dir no matter when the program is now in the process, zip it automatically

This function is called on loop 10 times for different directories

```
func (n Node) Build(path string) error {
    //e.g. Run npm install which build's nodejs project
    command := exec.Command("npm", "install")
    command.Dir = n.path

 //start the execution 
  if err := command.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Failed to start cmd: %v", err)
  }



// Here I waiting to command to finish to zip the folder
if err := command.Wait(); err != nil {
   // Zip folder
}



  }
```

the main function is calling to it like following

```
func main() {

//Here I have loop which 

for _, dir := range dirs {

    switch dir.name {
    case "Java":
        Build(&Java{path})
    case "Go":
        Build(&Golang{path,cgoOptions},) 
    case "Node":
        Build(&Node{path})
    }
}
```

similar to this post
[Using inheritance of builders in GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264882/using-inheritance-of-builders-in-go)

Comment: Performance? If your files are large avoiding a copy would be a big plus.

Comment: You have two options, and you want to know which performs better, so try each one, measure the performance of each, and compare them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to start as many [goroutines](https://gobyexample.com/goroutines) as you have folders to parallelize the execution of your program and then wait for all goroutines to finish using a [wait group](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

Example:

```
import "sync"

func (n Node) Build(wg sync.WaitGroup, path string) error {
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()

    //e.g. Run npm install which build's nodejs project
    command := exec.Command("npm", "install")
    command.Dir = n.path

    //start the execution 
    if err := command.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to start cmd: %v", err)
    }

    // Here I waiting to command to finish to zip the folder
    if err := command.Wait(); err != nil {
       // Zip folder
    } 
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    node := ...
    for _, path := range dirs {
        go node.Build(wg, path)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

**UPD:** some explanations. We need a shared wait group object between the main process and all the goroutines. One can treat our goroutines as logical threads of execution. And the wait group as a thread-safe shared counter variable. Each goroutine in our case is a single logical job. That's why we [`Add()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Add) (i.e. increment) the wait group internal counter by `1` in the beginning of the *thread* and decrease it by `1` via [`Done()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Done) call before the exiting from the `Build()` function. And the [`Wait()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Wait) method of the wait group just blocks the execution of the main process until the internal counter becomes 0 again.

Comment: Thanks, can you please elaborate what is  `wg.Add(1) ` and should I provide external counter to it ?